# Severe: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'columnname' doesn't have a default value

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

```
 JSONArray newdata = new JSONArray(tabledata);

 int prep = 0;
 String add_sie = "INSERT INTO " + table + " " +
    "(" + yearcolumn + "," + orgcolumn + "," + suborgcolumn + "," + amount + "," + createdbycolumn + "," + createddatecolumn + "," + statuscolumn + " , " + createdtimecolumn + " )" +
    " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

 preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(add_sie);
 for (int i = 0; i < newdata.length(); i++) {

    preparedStatement.setString(1, newdata.getJSONObject(i).get("year").toString());
    preparedStatement.setString(2, newdata.getJSONObject(i).get("org").toString());
    preparedStatement.setString(3, newdata.getJSONObject(i).get("sub_org").toString());
    preparedStatement.setString(4, newdata.getJSONObject(i).get("sub_org_amt").toString());
    preparedStatement.setString(5, af_mas_bi_createdby);
    preparedStatement.setString(6, af_mas_bi_datecreated);
    preparedStatement.setString(7, af_mas_bi_timecreated);
    preparedStatement.setString(8, "approved");
    //preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

    //preparedStatement.executeBatch();

 }
 preparedStatement.executeBatch();
```

I get error `Severe:   java.sql.SQLException: Field 'abap_id' doesn't have a default value` which is the id i place in database it structure is

[image]

Why do i get error in that id even if it is auto increment and i dont put it in insert with specific value

Comment: Pretty much what is says, the column doesn't have a default value and you are not assigning a value to it.

Comment: @e4c5 but it is auto increment it will increment after adding values right i put the print screen of the structure for that purpose to prove that it is auto increment

Comment: worst case, you can insert a `null` to it, which will trigger generation of a new auto_inc value.

Comment: is that the column? Well it's hardly clear from the screenshot you provided. it's not clear from your java code either since that is a massive string concatanation.

Comment: @e4c5 sorry it the information was not clear enough. yes it is autoincrement and i didnt put any value to it in the insert query.

Answer (score 0):

```
 String add_sie = "INSERT INTO " + table + " " +
"(abap_id," + yearcolumn + "," + orgcolumn + "," + suborgcolumn + "," + amount + "," + createdbycolumn + "," + createddatecolumn + "," + statuscolumn + " , " + createdtimecolumn + " )" +
" VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

**Important**! If you don't set the value to null or NULL and insert values manually, then the **AUTO_INCREMENT** seed is not updated. This may lead to **unique constraint violation errors** if the AUTO_INCREMENT column has an UNIQUE constraint or is a **PRIMARY KEY**.

Comment: tried this one as well same error... could it be because of the concat?